# How can I run R and python codes in Rstudio?

Tags: python, r, rstudio

I am using Rstudio to code with R and VScode for python. is there any way to run both r and python codes with Rstudio?
Thanks.

Comment: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500007929061-Using-Python-with-the-RStudio-IDE

Comment: If you already have python installed, you could probably just do this in Rstudio: File -> New File -> Python Script